# Drush won't run, 'status' shows web directory twice

Tags: drush

I have a multi-site Drupal 8 install and Drush has stopped working. All Drush commands fail with a "Bootstrap failed" error.

"Drush status" shows the /web dir twice as the root. Manually adding the root (--root:path) results in the same 'Bootstrap Failed" error

Any idea why the web directory would show twice in the root?

```
SITE@mi3-sr25 [~/public_html/web]# drush status
 PHP binary    : /opt/alt/php73/usr/bin/php
 PHP config    : /opt/alt/php73/etc/php.ini
 PHP OS        : Linux
 Drush script  : /home/SITE/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush
 Drush version : 9.7.3
 Drush temp    : /tmp
 Drush configs : /home/SITE/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml
 Drupal root   : /home/SITE/public_html/web/web
```

I've tried Drush 9 and 10. Checked for any duplicate directories, temporarily removed .htaccess No change.

Comment: Instead of editing your question with SOLVED, you should add an answer with the SOLVED info.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that there were copies of the composer.json and composer.lock files in the /web directory. I removed those and now everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was happening because I was calling an 'external' drush on the system.
While at the same time, a 'local' drush was inside the vendor/ folder via composer requirements.

Same effect: webroot shows twice. Some drush commands running twice.

I simply moved on and started calling the drush inside vendor/, using a symlink for convenience.